# understanding derivatives of a regression spline

Tags: regression, self-study, splines, derivative

I am trying to understand why regression splines are continuous at their knots

Suppose I am fitting a regression spline

$$
E[Y|X] = \alpha + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 (x - t)^+
$$

where $(x - t)^+ = \max (x-t,0)$.

Now, if I take the partial derivative of $y$ wrt $x$, I find

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 
\begin{cases}
\beta_1 \quad \text{if} \quad x \leq t,\\
\beta_1 + \beta_2 \quad \text{if} \quad x > t
\end{cases}
$$

For starters, is this correct?

If it is, I don't see how this shows the derivative at $t$ is continuous - it looks like there is a discrete change rather than smooth change

Comment: I am learning from your question. What is a good example for x & x-t ? and how is the 1st derivate beta1 when x<=t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly found the derivative.

With linear splines, the function is continuous but its first derivative is not; there's a jump discontinuity at each knot.